# json.dumps adds '"__pydantic_initialised__": true' to object

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

I am experimenting with fastapi and data from json files. When I add an object via app.put json.dumps adds an attribute `"__pydantic_initialised__": true` to my new object.

I start with two users:

```
print(users)
{
'456rtz': 
    User(vname='Niemand', nname='Nixda', email='niemand@nixda.none', 
    role=3, mobile=0, street='', city='Zürich', zip=0, country='', 
    id='456rtz'), 
'839f06fa-aa8c-4a77-9c5c-c036f913b18a': 
    User(vname='Paulchen', nname='Panther', email='pp@00.org', 
    role=3, mobile=0, street='', city='', zip=0, country='', 
    id='839f06fa-aa8c-4a77-9c5c-c036f913b18a')
}
```

Then I add a user:

```
users[user.id] = user
print(users)
{
'456rtz': 
    User(vname='Niemand', nname='Nixda', email='niemand@nixda.none', 
    role=3, mobile=0, street='', city='Zürich', zip=0, country='', 
    id='456rtz'), 
'839f06fa-aa8c-4a77-9c5c-c036f913b18a': 
    User(vname='Paulchen', nname='Panther', email='pp@00.org', 
    role=3, mobile=0, street='', city='', zip=0, country='', 
    id='839f06fa-aa8c-4a77-9c5c-c036f913b18a'), 
'3589f47b-79bf-4a3a-bc46-612386eed3e9': 
    User(vname='Tom', nname='Cat', email='java@land.com', 
    role=3, mobile=0, street='', city='', zip=0, country='', 
    id='3589f47b-79bf-4a3a-bc46-612386eed3e9')
}
```

To save all my users I convert this dictionary of User-objects to json like so:

```
dstring = json.dumps([vars(item) for item in users.values()], indent=4)
```

Just to make this point clear: The commands `print(users)`, `dstring=json.dumps(...` and the following `print(dstring)` follow one another - nothing else is between them.

Now something very annoying happens: json.dumps adds an attribute `"__pydantic_initialised__": true` to the new User-object-string in the json.dump:

```
print(dstring)

[
    {
        "vname": "Niemand",
        "nname": "Nixda",
        "email": "niemand@nixda.none",
        "role": 3,
        "mobile": 0,
        "street": "",
        "city": "Zurich",
        "zip": 0,
        "country": "",
        "id": "456rtz"
    },
    {
        "vname": "Paulchen",
        "nname": "Panther",
        "email": "pp@00.org",
        "role": 3,
        "mobile": 0,
        "street": "",
        "city": "",
        "zip": 0,
        "country": "",
        "id": "839f06fa-aa8c-4a77-9c5c-c036f913b18a"
    },
    {
        "vname": "Tom",
        "nname": "Cat",
        "email": "java@land.com",
        "role": 3,
        "mobile": 0,
        "street": "",
        "city": "",
        "zip": 0,
        "country": "",
        "id": "3589f47b-79bf-4a3a-bc46-612386eed3e9",
        "__pydantic_initialised__": true
    }
]
```

As my User-class has no attribute "**pydantic_initialised**" the program crashes when I try to read the users from file again.

What I find very strange: When I add multiple users one after another and then build the json, the dump adds this attribute to every new user.

Why does json.dumps do that, how does it distinguish the existing users from the new ones and - most important - how can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: `json.dumps()` isn't adding anything.  That attribute was already on the item.  It didn't appear in the output from your `print(users)` code examples because the `User` object has a custom `__str__` method that simply chooses not to display that attribute.

Comment: This thread might be helpful https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4149

Comment: Thanks a lot for this valuable input, John!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `vars(item)` will include internal fields to the Python class. Try using [Pydantic's `.dict()` method](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) instead:

```py
dstring = json.dumps([item.dict() for item in users.values()], indent=4)
```

Comment: Just to add, you technically don't even need to call `json.dumps` at all to export models. The `BaseModel.json` method exists for this purpose. If you have a dictionary of `str`-Model-pairs, you could define a custom root type for it and simply call its `json` method.

Comment: Thank you both! Unfortunatly my object doesn't have a dict-method, as it's built from @dataclass. But fastapi uses pydantic to initialise the model:

```
dstring = json.dumps([item.dict() for item in data.values()], indent=4)
                          ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'dict'
```

But with your input I'll find a way around. Thanks again!

Comment: can't you use:

from dataclasses import asdict

dstring = asdict(users)

?

Comment: @edgarbc If these were dataclasses, yes, that is the method to convert to a dictionary. Pydantic is a different library that does similar things as dataclasses, and there the way is to use the `.dict()` method on the class itself (in Pydantic V2 this has been renamed to `.model_dump()`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your help I found the solution: I added a dict-method to my dataclass:

```
def dict(self):
        return {k: str(v) for k, v in asdict(self).items()}
```

Then `dstring = json.dumps([item.dict() for item in users.values()], indent=4)` works for my case as M.O. wrote.